# iptables: policy DROP for INPUT does not affect localhost

Tags: iptables

I am surprised.

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Why can I still access localhost?
I would expect that all input traffic gets dropped.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. IPv4 was dropped but then IPv6 was used.

After I set the policy with ip6tables it was as expected.